# LearnDash + WooCommerce + WPML - некорректно отображаются курсы в кабинете студента

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт по продаже медицинских курсов.
При покупке трёх из 6-ти курсов, в личном кабинете отображаются только три курсы ( как и полагается). При переходе на испанский язык - отображаются эти купленные курсы, и ещё три курса ( которые я не покупал никогда).
В товарах woocommerce - есть привязка определённого товара к определённому курсу как на английском, так и на испанском языках.

https://snag.gy/YlJaiE.jpg - кабинет на английском.

https://snag.gy/kZeqx7.jpg - кабинет на испанском ( красным выделены купленные курсы ).

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, уже голову сломал.

Comment: Да не факт, что этот LearnDash вообще совместим с WPML

Comment: совместим, это 100%, просто только это и не работает, с остальным всё норм

Comment: Не факт. WPML - очень мощная штука, и почти все подхватывает. Но иногда код должен сам выдать страницу с переводом. Еще вариант - настройки WPML неправильные. Там в параметрах перевода надо указать тип записей, что соответствует купленному курсу, и отметить его как переводимый

Comment: Если не поможет - остается только нанимать фрилансера. Здесь мы вряд ли раскопаем причину. WPML создал клуб сертифицированных контракторов. Вот перечнь русскоговорящих: https://wpml.org/contractors/?wpv_view_count=1435673&wpv-wpcf-how-big-projects-can-you-handle=&wpv-wpcf-do-you-provide-maintenance=+&wpv-wpcf-how-small-projects-can-you-take=&wpv-contractor-language%5B%5D=ru

Comment: @KAGGDesign можно подробнее, какие именно настройки нужно глянуть в параметрах перевода ?

Comment: http://take.ms/C54sL

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо за помощь, увы, в настройках уже проставлен тип записей.....

Comment: @KAGGDesign написали в техподдержку, они сказали проверить тип цены в продукте, и убедиться что она не "Open", я проверил, она не открытая, а "Buy now"....